# create sql query to fetch repeat column values within time frame

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone help me with this query? I want to get the result of all the `customer_id` which repeats more than once in 24hrs

```
SELECT 
    O.Order_No, O.Customer_ID, O.DateOrdered, O.IPAddress,
    C.FirstName, C.LastName, CD.nameoncard
FROM 
    Order_No O
INNER JOIN 
    CardData CD ON O.card_id = CD.id
INNER JOIN 
    Customers C ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id   
ORDER BY
    O.order_no desc
```

adding more details..
so suppose  order with customer id xx was placed on 04/23 2:30 pm and again 2nd order was placed with same customer Id xx on same day 04/23 5:30 pm.

i want the query to return me customer Id xx

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Customer_ID, CAST(DateOrdered as Date) DateOrdered, count(*) QTDE
from Order_No
group by Customer_ID, CAST(DateOrdered as Date)
having count(*) > 1
```

To get the customers who have orders issued after the **first** one, then you could use the following query:

```
select distinct A.Customer_ID
from Order_No A
inner join (select Customer_ID, min(DateOrdered) DateOrdered from Order_No group by Customer_ID ) B
  on A.Customer_ID = B.Customer_ID
  and A.DateOrdered - B.DateOrdered <= 1
  and A.DateOrdered > B.DateOrdered
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/deead/6)

To get all customers that have ANY TIME more than one order issued in period less or equal than 24h

```
select distinct A.Customer_ID
from Order_No A
inner join Order_No B
  on A.Customer_ID = B.Customer_ID
  and A.DateOrdered > B.DateOrdered
  and A.DateOrdered - B.DateOrdered <= 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/deead/7)

Comment: how will this query get me all customer id within 24 hours?

Comment: When you say 24h, you are saying the same day, or actually 24h?

Comment: And you are saying last 24h or any 24h?

Comment: yeah so basically if order with same customer Id exists within 24 hours of 1st order placed

Answer (score 0):

Self-join:

```
SELECT distinct O.Customer_ID
FROM 
Order_No O
inner join Order_No o2
on o.customerID = o2.customerID 
    and datediff(hour, o.DateOrdered, o2.DateOrdered) between 0 and 24
and o.Order_No <> o2.Order_No
```

This will return all customer_IDs that have ever placed more than one order in any 24 hour period.

Edited to add the join criteria that the matching records should not be the same record.  Should return customers who placed two different orders at the same time, but not customers who placed only one order.

Comment: This will return the same orders in O and O2. That is why you need to have any ohter condition where O.DateOrdered < O2.DateOrdered

Comment: It just returns distinct customer IDs, so this shouldn't matter, but edited to eliminate negative datediff results anyway. thanks @nizam.

Comment: Look what I am saying http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/deead/9. It is choosing 1,2 and 3. I think it should choose just 1 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/deead/10)

Comment: Ohh, thanks @Nizam.  Makes sense.  I will edit to correct that.  Sorry, I didn't understand what you were saying in your original comment.